# Returning an STL vector from a function - copy cost

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

When you return an stl vector from a function:

```
vector<int> getLargeArray() {  ...  }
```

Is the return going to be an expensive copy operation?  I remember reading somewhere that vector assignment being fast -- should I require the caller to pass a reference instead?

```
void getLargeArray( vector<int>& vec ) {  ...  }
```

Comment: @Gareth Except when you're in C++11, where returning a vector from a function is **garanteed** to be fast **by standard** (aside from return value optimization even making it fast in pre-C++11 in many cases, but Ok, that one's implementation and situation dependent).

Comment: This post may be of interest: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming  your function constructs and returns new data, you should return by value, and try to make sure that the function itself has one return point that returns a variable of type `vector<int>`, or at worst several return points that all return the same variable.

That ensures that you'll get the named return value optimization on any credible compiler, which eliminates *one* of the potential copies (the one from the value in the function, to the return value). There are other ways to get a return value optimization, but it's not wholly predictable so the simple rule plays safe.

Next, you want to eliminate the potential copy from the return value to whatever the caller does with it. It's the caller's problem to solve, not the callee's, and there are basically three ways to do this:

- Use the call to the function as the initializer for a `vector<int>`, in which case again any credible C++ compiler will elide the copy.
- Use C++11, where `vector` has move semantics.
- In C++03, use "swaptimization".

That is, in C++03 *don't* write

```
vector<int> v;
// use v for some stuff
// ...
// now I want fresh data in v:
v = getLargeArray();
```

Instead:

```
getLargeArray().swap(v);
```

This avoids the copy assignment that's required (must not be elided[*]) for `v = getLargeArray()`. It's not needed in C++11, where there's a cheap move assignment instead of the expensive copy assignment, but of course it still works.

Another thing to consider is whether you actually want `vector` as part of your interface. You could instead perhaps write a function template that takes an output iterator, and writes the data to that output iterator. Callers who want the data in a vector can then pass in the result of `std::back_inserter`, and so can callers who want the data in a `deque` or `list`. Callers who know the size of the data in advance could even pass just a vector iterator (suitably `resize()`d first) or a raw pointer to a large enough array, to avoid the overhead of `back_insert_iterator`. There are non-template ways of doing the same thing, but they'll most likely incur a call overhead one way or another. If you're worried about the cost of copying an `int` per element, then you're worried about the cost of a function call per element.

If your function doesn't construct and return new data, but rather it returns the current contents of some existing `vector<int>` and isn't allowed to change the original, then you can't avoid at least one copy when you return by value. So if the performance of that is a proven problem, then you need to look at some API other than return-by-value. For example you might supply a pair of iterators that can be used to traverse the internal data, a function to look up a value in the vector by index, or even (if the performance problem is so serious as to warrant exposing your internals), a reference to the vector. Obviously in all those cases you change the meaning of the function -- now instead of giving the caller "their own data" it provides a view of someone else's data, which might change.

[*] of course the "as if" rule still applies, and one can imagine a C++ implementation that's smart enough to realise that since this is a vector of a trivially copyable type (`int`), and since you haven't taken any pointers to any elements (I assume), then it can swap instead and the result is "as if" it copied. But I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 10):

You are very likely to get [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), depending on the structure of the function body. In C++11 you could also benefit from move semantics.
Returning by value certainly has cleaner semantics, and I would see it as the preferred option, unless profiling proves it to be costly. There is a good related article [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Here is a small example with a verbose dummy class, compiled with no optimization or C++11 support, using an old-ish version of GCC (4.3.4):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct Foo
{
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()\n"; }
  Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "Foo copy\n"; }
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) { 
    std::cout << "Foo assignment\n"; 
    return *this;
  }
};

std::vector<Foo> makeFoos()
{
  std::vector<Foo> tmp;
  tmp.push_back(Foo());
  std::cout << "returning\n";
  return tmp;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> foos = makeFoos();
}
```

The result on my platform is that all copying happens before the function return. If I compile with C++11 support, then the push_back results in a move copy rather than a C++03 copy construction.

Comment: Actually, you are only very likely to get RVO if you always return the same vector...

Comment: @ltjax yes, that goes under "structure of the function body". Since it isn't written in the standard, I didn't want to elaborate too much.