# Stack std::vector scope

Tags: c++, vector, scope, return-value

im new to c++ and i'm finding hard to understand some vector behaviours.
I was trying to implement a function to return an array of int and i found many suggestions to use a vector like this:

```
vector<int> myFunc()
{
    vector<int> myVector;
    //add elements to vector here...
    return myVector;
}
```

But from what i know 'myVector' is an object created on the stack, so isnt it going out of scope when the function end? when does its destructor get called?
I know there are few other questions about returning vectors, but i need to clarify this specific point, hoping to not have duplicated a question.

Comment: It gets copied/moved (or optimized out). It's returning the address of, or a reference to, a local object that can cause problems.

Comment: There are a plethora of questions on SO about this subject. you may find them ([sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604431/returning-an-stl-vector-from-a-function-copy-cost)) enlightening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes because `myVector` is allocated on the stack, as soon as the function returns, it goes out of scope. But in this case that's ok! Your function signature is

```
vector<int> myFunc()
```

which returns a *copy* of `myVector` so it doesn't matter that it's going out of scope since it's already being copied for the return.

However if you changed it to something like

```
vector<int> & myFunc()
```

now your telling it not to copy `myVector` and you'll have a problem called a *dangling reference* since `myVector` will be destructed and you don't copy it but still try to use it.

Comment: so is this vector-specific? i mean is this ok because vector have a copy costructor that also duplicate dynamic allocated internal data?

Comment: It's true of any well designed container of class following the rule of 3 (or since C++11 5). For classes without internal dynamic data, they'll get this for free.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns a **copy** of the `myVector` instance on the stack. So it's OK it goes out of scope and is deleted (after return).

Comment: copied or moved, depending if C++11 move ctors are supported.

Answer (score 0):

It does go out of scope, but when you return a class or struct, the compiler automatically makes a copy for you, so that your receiving object is filled in with the content of the original object.

Similar to:

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int> b;

... fill in vector a with stuff ... 

b = a;
```